# Cannot fix Heroku H10 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, puma

I have read every single SO answer I can find on H10 errors, and am still unable to fix the issue. My app works fine in dev, but in production I get the useless "Application Error" message, and the logs only give me a tiny amount of information. The app was working, and the only major change thats been made since then was using Puma in production (created a config/puma.rb file and a Procfile), as I've been following the Rails Tutorial.

Logs:

```
    2015-03-01T00:21:46.250486+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    2015-03-01T00:21:46.250482+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:36909
    2015-03-01T00:21:46.250452+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
    2015-03-01T00:21:47.672814+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:36909
    2015-03-01T00:21:47.672797+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma 2.11.1 starting...
    2015-03-01T00:21:47.672812+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
    2015-03-01T00:21:47.672804+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
    2015-03-01T00:21:47.995124+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2015-03-01T01:25:01.069619+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
    2015-03-01T01:25:01.070164+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
    2015-03-01T01:25:03.868187+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
    2015-03-01T01:25:04.655669+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
    2015-03-01T01:25:05.901550+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
    2015-03-03T18:18:29.133217+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
    2015-03-03T18:18:29.133564+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
    2015-03-03T18:18:34.226482+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 32028 -e production`
    2015-03-03T18:18:39.475492+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
    2015-03-03T18:18:39.475519+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:32028
    2015-03-03T18:18:39.475521+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
    2015-03-03T18:18:39.475522+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    2015-03-03T18:18:40.951238+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
    2015-03-03T18:18:40.951182+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma 2.11.1 starting...
    2015-03-03T18:18:40.951281+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
    2015-03-03T18:18:40.951344+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:32028
    2015-03-03T18:18:41.226254+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/about" for 108.94.29.164 at         2015-03-03 18:18:41 +0000
    2015-03-03T18:18:41.711420+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by StaticPagesController#about as HTML
    2015-03-03T18:18:41.776431+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.5ms)
    2015-03-03T18:18:41.055292+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
    2015-03-03T18:18:41.769299+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered static_pages/about.html.erb within layouts/application (0.7ms)
    2015-03-03T18:18:41.780270+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.8ms)
    2015-03-03T18:18:41.780272+00:00 app[web.1]:   Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.6ms)
    2015-03-03T18:18:41.780273+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 58ms (Views: 40.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
    2015-03-03T18:18:41.785426+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/about" host=alecfwilson-sample-rails-app.herokuapp.com request_id=f01990b2-55ef-4bb5-99ba-635bd06d211d fwd="108.94.29.164" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=585ms status=200 bytes=2600
    2015-03-03T18:18:43.046815+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-3693022c438b060c15d38fbd42afb0dd.css" host=alecfwilson-sample-rails-app.herokuapp.com request_id=4777c80d-585c-4e9a-a260-df8e498d5aef fwd="108.94.29.164" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=100
    2015-03-03T18:18:43.088423+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-40a1932d75f4dbff6f274ab2c04c99ef.js" host=alecfwilson-sample-rails-app.herokuapp.com request_id=3418bdae-28fa-45c0-adf4-e121b7a65341 fwd="108.94.29.164" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=114
    2015-03-03T18:18:45.693979+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=alecfwilson-sample-rails-app.herokuapp.com request_id=1ec2d858-f4f4-4130-83ed-9835a6b8aee4 fwd="108.94.29.164" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=200 bytes=143
    2015-03-03T19:25:51.614540+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
    2015-03-03T19:25:51.615133+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
    2015-03-03T19:25:54.642520+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
    2015-03-03T19:25:55.360332+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
    2015-03-03T19:25:56.374683+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
    2015-03-04T02:32:30.738201+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy ada64bd by alec.f.wilson@gmail.com
    2015-03-04T02:32:30.738201+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v15 created by alec.f.wilson@gmail.com
    2015-03-04T02:32:43.267564+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by alec.f.wilson@gmail.com
    2015-03-04T02:32:47.471977+00:00 heroku[run.5036]: Awaiting client
    2015-03-04T02:32:47.501831+00:00 heroku[run.5036]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
    2015-03-04T02:32:47.757400+00:00 heroku[run.5036]: State changed from starting to up
    2015-03-04T02:32:53.981368+00:00 heroku[run.5036]: Process exited with status 0
    2015-03-04T02:32:53.997726+00:00 heroku[run.5036]: State changed from up to complete
    2015-03-04T02:33:00.228053+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
    2015-03-04T02:33:00.228382+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
    2015-03-04T02:33:05.010249+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
    2015-03-04T02:33:07.896116+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:179:in `_load_from'
    2015-03-04T02:33:07.896123+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
    2015-03-04T02:33:07.896099+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:179:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - config/puma.rb (Errno::ENOENT)
    2015-03-04T02:33:07.896127+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
    2015-03-04T02:33:07.896120+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/cli.rb:308:in `parse_options'
    2015-03-04T02:33:07.896118+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:40:in `load'
    2015-03-04T02:33:07.896121+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/cli.rb:453:in `run'
    2015-03-04T02:33:07.896128+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
    2015-03-04T02:33:08.726223+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2015-03-04T02:33:08.726988+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2015-03-04T02:33:08.714157+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2015-03-04T02:33:12.828442+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
    2015-03-04T02:33:16.051228+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2015-03-04T02:33:16.031660+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2015-03-04T02:33:17.607265+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=alecfwilson-sample-rails-app.herokuapp.com request_id=cc813454-8a73-46b1-9f2f-398653e718b6 fwd="73.162.223.27" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2015-03-04T02:33:17.807509+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=alecfwilson-sample-rails-app.herokuapp.com request_id=0f04159b-e864-4a16-8c6d-aee891f112b3 fwd="73.162.223.27" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2015-03-04T02:33:18.286091+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/about" host=alecfwilson-sample-rails-app.herokuapp.com request_id=bdee0496-b545-4f15-88fc-1ebd92869e64 fwd="73.162.223.27" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2015-03-04T02:33:18.965330+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=alecfwilson-sample-rails-app.herokuapp.com request_id=364c0e82-2cb8-4613-845a-093a09bfb663 fwd="73.162.223.27" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2015-03-04T02:33:15.303042+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/cli.rb:308:in `parse_options'
    2015-03-04T02:33:15.303046+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/cli.rb:453:in `run'
    2015-03-04T02:33:15.303018+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:179:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - config/puma.rb (Errno::ENOENT)
    2015-03-04T02:33:15.303051+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
    2015-03-04T02:33:15.303040+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:40:in `load'
    2015-03-04T02:33:15.303049+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
    2015-03-04T02:33:15.303037+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:179:in `_load_from'
    2015-03-04T02:33:15.303047+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
    2015-03-04T02:33:22.485187+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=alecfwilson-sample-rails-app.herokuapp.com request_id=68be4767-c94f-41b1-84fe-9f7fc95e6f4c fwd="73.162.223.27" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2015-03-04T02:33:22.954529+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=alecfwilson-sample-rails-app.herokuapp.com request_id=65918dc8-be1f-4875-997d-a9507b141182 fwd="73.162.223.27" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2015-03-04T02:33:23.061083+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=alecfwilson-sample-rails-app.herokuapp.com request_id=ea5e39cf-0b11-482b-a0c2-53f9068eca5f fwd="73.162.223.27" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2015-03-04T02:37:48.220193+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=alecfwilson-sample-rails-app.herokuapp.com request_id=be8d1130-94d0-42b7-95ae-e73e5bae3c2d fwd="73.162.223.27" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2015-03-04T02:37:49.023244+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=alecfwilson-sample-rails-app.herokuapp.com request_id=7b8ba657-f700-4519-8cda-7ee709aacdf1 fwd="73.162.223.27" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2015-03-04T02:37:49.322225+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=alecfwilson-sample-rails-app.herokuapp.com request_id=53642f7e-a8ad-4279-b619-2e482155e792 fwd="73.162.223.27" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2015-03-04T02:38:25.709950+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v16 created by alec.f.wilson@gmail.com
    2015-03-04T02:38:25.709950+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy bf99108 by alec.f.wilson@gmail.com
    2015-03-04T02:38:26.037514+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
    2015-03-04T02:38:29.655020+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
    2015-03-04T02:38:32.015466+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:179:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - config/puma.rb (Errno::ENOENT)
    2015-03-04T02:38:32.015483+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:179:in `_load_from'
    2015-03-04T02:38:32.015486+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/configuration.rb:40:in `load'
    2015-03-04T02:38:32.015487+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/cli.rb:308:in `parse_options'
    2015-03-04T02:38:32.015493+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/bin/puma:10:in `<top (required)>'
    2015-03-04T02:38:32.015495+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/puma:23:in `load'
    2015-03-04T02:38:32.015491+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.11.1/lib/puma/cli.rb:453:in `run'
    2015-03-04T02:38:32.015497+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/puma:23:in `<main>'
    2015-03-04T02:38:32.719386+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
    2015-03-04T02:38:32.739368+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
    2015-03-04T02:38:34.073282+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=alecfwilson-sample-rails-app.herokuapp.com request_id=d97ef726-cdcc-4724-ad8d-506f71c36da6 fwd="73.162.223.27" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2015-03-04T02:38:34.756462+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=alecfwilson-sample-rails-app.herokuapp.com request_id=b64b5c74-00de-406a-a769-a6771b5ffabd fwd="73.162.223.27" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
    2015-03-04T02:38:35.037847+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=alecfwilson-sample-rails-app.herokuapp.com request_id=90f3b563-de59-4107-a8fe-d613cf98aefd fwd="73.162.223.27" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I've already run `$ heroku run rake db:migrate`, `$ heroku restart`, and reset the production database. What else can I do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed. Going line by line through the logs, found that I had my puma.rb file in the wrong location.